# Space in file path is replaced with (null)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to check if the current desktop wallpaper has a specific file name. I want to do this by appending the file name to `desktopImageURLForScreen` and using `fileExistsAtPath` to check if that file exists (not a perfect solution, but it works for my purposes). Here is my code:

```
guard let wallpaperDirectoryURL = workspace.desktopImageURLForScreen(screen)
    else { NSLog("Error getting desktop image URL."); return }

let URLToCheckIfExists = wallpaperDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(lastId).jpg")
let stringToCheckIfExists = URLToCheckIfExists.absoluteString
print(stringToCheckIfExists)
let lastIdIsCurrentWallpaper = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(stringToCheckIfExists)
```

My problem is that when there is a space in the file path, the string for the file path replaces the space AND the character after it with (null).

So instead of a path like:

`/Users/Joe/Library/Application Support/Wallpaperer/Wallpapers/4d65y1.jpg`

I get:

`/Users/Joe/Library/Application(null)upport/Wallpaperer/Wallpapers/4d65y1.jpg`

What is happening here? How can I get the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out the problem pretty quickly. I should be using `URLToCheckIfExists.path` instead of `URLToCheckIfExists.absoluteString`.